# Ember Data Access App initialization

Tags: ember.js

at the moment im really frustrated. I ll try to get table filled with some data of my database. Therefore i have a controller and a View.

```
App.TableController.extend({
   content: [],
   contentBinding:'App.incidient.content'
  })
App.TableView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  tagName: 'tbody',
  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'table'
})
```

My html code looks like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
              Title
            </th>
            <th>
              Customer
            </th>
            <th>
              Machine
            </th>
            <th>
              Priortity
            </th>
            <th>
              Status
            </th>               
        </tr>
        <thead>
  {{view App.TableView}}
</table>
 </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="table">
  {{#each item in content}}
            <td> 
               {{view item.incidient.title}}
            </td>
            <td> 
              {{view item.incidient.customer}}
            </td>
            <td> 
              {{view item.incidient.machine}}
            </td>
            <td> 
              {{view item.incidient.priority}}
            </td>
            <td> 
              {{view item.incidient.status}}
           </td>  
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

Im not frustrated because of my the code that is not working. It is more about the fact that:

1. i dont find any good guide or post where i can see how to debug my Application. The      Debugging tool from Chrome doesnt help at all, because i can't figure out how to get access to the content of my TableController or better where i can find it.
2. i dont understand where the App is initializing all of my Controllers and how i can access them. With the old router: it was like 'App.router.myController' but this is not working anymore.
3. i dont know how to access datas from a different controller. I tried to bind the Table.Controller.content to the 'App.incidient.content' and Ember didnt even throw an exception or something

I hope you can help. I dont think that these question are really difficult to answer but for a noobie like me they are quite fundamental.

Greeting and thank you

Alex

Comment: I get your frustration with outdated tutorials and samples, but if it helps, Trek is [tracking them](https://github.com/trek/ember-outdated-articles) in order to notify article authors about these things. In regards to your question, your `TableController` doesn't seem to be correct (what are you extending?). Is there any chance you could add *more* code to the question, I'm seeing a number of things that don't quite make sense, like when you're calling `{{view App.TableView}}` without a loop. I'd say you should check this: http://tinyurl.com/emberwalkthrough

Comment: well yes you are right i missed the loop. The whole day i tried different things, unfortunately it felt like "try and error", so as i posted this, ive forgot to change it back to the thing i really tried. Anyway thanks a lot for the tutorial. Hopefully it will help me

Comment: If you can afford I **strongly** recommend [this screencast](https://peepcode.com/products/emberjs) (only 12 bucks)